# making a from, to network in three column data frame in r

Tags: r

i hope everyone is doing well, I have problem to make a network of editors in a wikipedia articles within a single  article (when one article finish start another article networks) the networks will be later used to find the degree centrality of both users and articles.  the data frame looks like

```
faID           uName                     time_Stamp
 1               Qaless                 2003-09-06T20:27:00Z
 1               Austin                 2003-10-31T06:07:03Z
 1               SimonP                 2004-02-10T19:15:56Z
 1               SimonP                 2004-02-10T19:23:44Z
 1             Moncrief                2004-02-10T19:28:09Z
 1             Moncrief                2004-02-10T19:28:48Z
 1                  Rbs                2004-02-10T20:21:35Z
 1            Camembert                2004-02-10T20:27:34Z
 2             Moncrief                2004-02-10T20:29:33Z
 2                  Rbs                2004-02-10T20:39:33Z
 2              Jason M                2004-05-18T23:54:15Z
 2             Rickyrab                2004-05-28T05:35:32Z
 2             Rickyrab                2004-05-28T05:37:10Z
 2              Postdlf                2004-06-08T03:26:25Z
 2              Modster               2004-08-10T17:22:37Z
 3            PhilHibbs               2004-08-23T14:09:54Z
 3             Sfoskett               2004-09-10T18:22:15Z
 3               Dalton               2004-09-12T17:34:13Z
 3               Dalton               2004-09-12T17:38:35Z
 3      Ta bu shi da yu               2004-09-17T07:24:10Z
```

I want to have a data frame of network which will looks like

```
faid      to         from        time stamp 
 1         Qaless    Qaless        2003-09-06T20:27:00Z
 1        Qaless     Austin        2003-10-31T06:07:03Z
 1        Austin     SimonP        2004-02-10T19:15:56Z
 1        SimonP     SimonP        2004-02-10T19:23:44Z
 1        SimonP     Moncrief      2004-02-10T19:28:09Z
 1        Moncrief   Moncrief      2004-02-10T19:28:48Z
 1        Moncrief     Rbs         2004-02-10T20:21:35Z
 1        Camembert    Rbs         2004-02-10T20:27:34Z
 2        Moncrief   Moncrief      2004-02-10T20:29:33Z
 2        Moncrief    Rbs          2004-02-10T20:39:33Z
 2        Rbs        Jason M       2004-05-18T23:54:15Z
 2        jason M    Rickyrab     2004-05-28T05:35:32Z
 2        Rickyrab  Rickyrab      2004-05-28T05:37:10Z
 2        Rickyrab     Postdlf    2004-06-08T03:26:25Z
 2        Postdlf    modster      2004-08-10T17:22:37Z
 3        PhilHibbs PhilHibbs     2004-08-23T14:09:54Z
 3        PhilHibbs Sfoskett      2004-09-10T18:22:15Z 
 3        Sfoskett  Dalton        2004-09-12T17:34:13Z
 3        Dalton    Dalton        2004-09-12T17:38:35Z 
 3    dalton     Ta bu shi da yu  2004-09-17T07:24:10Z
```

general explanations are 
 to--> the person edit( i.e the with edit before the next person(below row)
from--> the person edit( below the person editing earlier)
so any help for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution using the newest `data.table` version

```
library(data.table) # v 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, to := shift(uName, fill = uName[1L]), by = faID]
setnames(df, "uName", "from")
df
#     faID            from           time_Stamp        to
#  1:    1          Qaless 2003-09-06T20:27:00Z    Qaless
#  2:    1          Austin 2003-10-31T06:07:03Z    Qaless
#  3:    1          SimonP 2004-02-10T19:15:56Z    Austin
#  4:    1          SimonP 2004-02-10T19:23:44Z    SimonP
#  5:    1        Moncrief 2004-02-10T19:28:09Z    SimonP
#  6:    1        Moncrief 2004-02-10T19:28:48Z  Moncrief
#  7:    1             Rbs 2004-02-10T20:21:35Z  Moncrief
#  8:    1       Camembert 2004-02-10T20:27:34Z       Rbs
#  9:    2        Moncrief 2004-02-10T20:29:33Z  Moncrief
# 10:    2             Rbs 2004-02-10T20:39:33Z  Moncrief
# 11:    2         Jason M 2004-05-18T23:54:15Z       Rbs
# 12:    2        Rickyrab 2004-05-28T05:35:32Z   Jason M
# 13:    2        Rickyrab 2004-05-28T05:37:10Z  Rickyrab
# 14:    2         Postdlf 2004-06-08T03:26:25Z  Rickyrab
# 15:    2         Modster 2004-08-10T17:22:37Z   Postdlf
# 16:    3       PhilHibbs 2004-08-23T14:09:54Z PhilHibbs
# 17:    3        Sfoskett 2004-09-10T18:22:15Z PhilHibbs
# 18:    3          Dalton 2004-09-12T17:34:13Z  Sfoskett
# 19:    3          Dalton 2004-09-12T17:38:35Z    Dalton
# 20:    3 Ta bu shi da yu 2004-09-17T07:24:10Z    Dalton
```

Comment: it gives me an error like  Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(na2), , `:=`(to, shift(uName, fill = uName[1L])),  : 
  could not find function "shift"

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that you need the devel version. Did you run `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` first like I showed?

Comment: yes I installed the library(devtools) but the error is the same

Comment: But did you run `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` **after** installing `devtools` library? Also, you need to run `library(data.table)` again afterwards.

Comment: I just simply follow your steps i.e. run library(devtools)   : run install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE): load a library(data.table)

Comment: after that  I just run this code                                                                                setDT(df)[, to := shift(uName, fill = uName[1L]), by = faID]                                                  but it gives me the above mentioned error

Comment: When you run `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` did you get any errors?

Comment: 1st part  Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="data.table.dll" OBJECTS="assign.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fastradixdouble.o fastradixint.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o transpose.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/data.table'
* restoring previous 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/data.table'

Comment: So it didn't work. Try closing **all** of your R sessions. Open **only one**. Then run `library(devtools) ; install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` and see if you still getting any errors.

Comment: 2nd part Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\library\00LOCK-Rdatatable-data.table-b6ea972\data.table\libs\x64\datatable.dll to C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\library\data.table\libs\x64\datatable.dll: Permission denied
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78303/discussion-between-naveed-khan-wazir-and-david-arenburg).

Answer (score 3):

If `df` is your original `data.frame`, you can do:

```
transform(df, 
             from = uName, 
             to = ave(as.character(uName), faID, FUN = function(x) c(x[1L], head(x,-1L))), 
             uName = NULL
           )

#    faID           time_Stamp            from        to
# 1     1 2003-09-06T20:27:00Z          Qaless    Qaless
# 2     1 2003-10-31T06:07:03Z          Austin    Qaless
# 3     1 2004-02-10T19:15:56Z          SimonP    Austin
# 4     1 2004-02-10T19:23:44Z          SimonP    SimonP
# 5     1 2004-02-10T19:28:09Z        Moncrief    SimonP
# 6     1 2004-02-10T19:28:48Z        Moncrief  Moncrief
# 7     1 2004-02-10T20:21:35Z             Rbs  Moncrief
# 8     1 2004-02-10T20:27:34Z       Camembert       Rbs
# 9     2 2004-02-10T20:29:33Z        Moncrief  Moncrief
# 10    2 2004-02-10T20:39:33Z             Rbs  Moncrief
# 11    2 2004-05-18T23:54:15Z         Jason M       Rbs
# 12    2 2004-05-28T05:35:32Z        Rickyrab   Jason M
# 13    2 2004-05-28T05:37:10Z        Rickyrab  Rickyrab
# 14    2 2004-06-08T03:26:25Z         Postdlf  Rickyrab
# 15    2 2004-08-10T17:22:37Z         Modster   Postdlf
# 16    3 2004-08-23T14:09:54Z       PhilHibbs PhilHibbs
# 17    3 2004-09-10T18:22:15Z        Sfoskett PhilHibbs
# 18    3 2004-09-12T17:34:13Z          Dalton  Sfoskett
# 19    3 2004-09-12T17:38:35Z          Dalton    Dalton
# 20    3 2004-09-17T07:24:10Z Ta bu shi da yu    Dalton
```